# dollar sign, comma, decimal places

Tags: sql

I have this code to get total and other fields. what I am interested in
to get total values with $ sign, comma and 02 decimal places, what will be
the best function to use to cover all these. 
so the total should reflect like :  $ 1,780.00

please advise

```
select distinct
    c.givenname, c.familyname, s.total, p.title,
    a.givenname+' '+a.familyname as artist
from
    customers as c
        join sales as s on c.id=s.customerid
        join saleitems as si on s.id=si.saleid  
        join paintings as p on si.paintingid=p.id   
        join artists as a on p.artistid=a.id;
```

---

result I am getting is like this:

```
Aloysius Peace  1780.0000 Woman in Black (Femme en noir)Mary Cassatt
Amanda  Lynn    1115.0000 Le Moulin de la Galette   Pierre-Auguste Renoir
Amanda  Lynn    1115.0000 Madamoiselle RiviereJean-Auguste-Dominique Ingres
Amanda  Lynn    1115.0000 Pollard Willows With SETting SunVincent Van Gogh
Amelia  Rate    2125.0000 Flowers in a Vase with Shells and InseBalthasar Van 
Amelia  Rate    2125.0000 The Meeting of St Anthony Abbot and St Paul in the 
Amelia  Rate    2125.0000 The Two Girlfriends   Henri de Toulouse-Lautrec
Amelia  Rate    2125.0000 Vision After the Sermon, Jacob Wrestling
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'd let the presentation layer fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this something like this in your code. (for MS SQL)

```
select '$' + cast(cast (s.total as decimal (9,2)) as varchar(20)) as price
```

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks, please advise why we use 02 cast in this statement just for my knowledge...

Comment: one thing I noticed if I use order by TotalPrice desc at the end of code , it doesn't do the correct desc order , any reason for this. please advise.

Comment: The decimal cast is to "fix" the data into a currency format and then because we're  prefixing with a currency symbol, the numbers are converted to a string to allow non-alphanumeric to be stored.

If you were presenting the data in SSRS or another presentation layer, you normally wouldn't bother.